# How to implement Excel Sort with levels in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sorting

I'm trying to figure out how to implement how excel sorts by levels if wanted in python with pandas (i.e. it sorts by column A, then by column B, then column C, etc.). Anyone have any advice with this?

Thank you.
[*image of example*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUfaN.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
df.sort_values(['column A','column B','column C'], ascending  = True)
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, it doesn't spit out any errors but it also doesn't actually do any sorting. A lot of the stuff I need to sort are alphanumerical strings, not values alone.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work! Forgot to reassign the above to df.